# Best site for posting Python code?

Tags: python

Which sites are the best for posting Python code that actually works? To show/share, and get input? I would like to post my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out ActiveState's [Python Recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/) site. It reminds me a bit of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I think Github (Git) or Bitbucket/Kiln (Mercurial) would be the best places to host any code. That way you can keep it in version control + get comments, suggestions, and even features or additional code for free via the pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best maybe, [google code](http://code.google.com/), [git](http://git-scm.com/) are all pretty good web site. Try one of them and find the one suit you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [pythonfiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/).